# Can I use a simple boolean to control a long running thread?

Tags: .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Throughout the years, I've always followed a simple pattern to create long-running workers (usually deployed as Windows Services) in my applications:

```
class LongRunningWorker
{
    public void Start() 
    {
        _isRunning = true;
        _thread = new Thread(DoWork);
        _thread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop() 
    {
        _isRunning = false;
        _thread.Join(TIMEOUT);
    }

    private void DoWork()
    { 
        while(_isRunning) 
        {
            // do work
            Thread.Sleep(INTERVAL);
        }

        // perform shutdown
    }
}
```

It has now occurred to me that I might have a race condition on the `isRunning` field; Furthermore, I usually forget to flag it as volatile to prevent caching. So, my questions:

1. Is there some risk of failure by using the field without a semaphore or any sort of `Interlocked` call? What sort of errors I can expect?
2. Given the answer to the previous question, is using `volatile` a necessity? In my example it certainly is, but if the answer to question 1 is to use a mutex or something, do I need to?
3. I also have a notion that a `BackgroundWorker` isn't a good solution to this kind of problem - it's a component to be used by front-ends (Windows Forms I guess) and not real asynchronous programs. But is this true? What are the trade-offs? Is there another class that removes the kind of boilerplate I'm writing?

Comment: I didn't make this an answer because I don'r know jack about .net , but if it's like certain other programming environments, then no "interlocking" means there won't be any guarantee about how long (if _ever_) it takes for the worker thread to notice that the other thread changed the value of the flag.

Comment: This is exactly what [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) is for, so you should just use that.

Answer (score 0):

For several years I used a slightly improved version, too. That worked very well in many projects. I used a `ManualResetEvent` to signal the stop event immediately and used the `ManualResetEvent.WaitOne(INTERVAL, false)` to delay the worker thread.

For .NET 4 and above, it is easier to user a `CancellationToken` instead, here is a simplified example:

```
  class LongRunningWorker : IDisposable
  {
    private volatile bool            _disposing    = false;
    private volatile bool            _isDisposed   = false;
    private CancellationTokenSource  _cancelSource = null;
    private System.Threading.Thread  _thread       = null;

    public LongRunningWorker() 
    {
    }            

    public void Start() 
    {
      if(_disposing || _isDisposed)
        throw new ObjectDisposedException("LongRunningWorker");

      RecreateCancellationSource();

      _thread              = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoWork));
      _thread.IsBackground = true; // do not block process termination
      _thread.Start((object)_cancelSource.Token); // copy cancellation token by value, used as the callback argument
    }

    public void Stop() 
    {
      if(_disposing || _isDisposed)
        return;

      _cancelSource.Cancel();
    }

    private void DoWork(object state)
    {
      CancellationToken cancelToken = (CancellationToken)state;

      while(!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested) 
      {
        try
        {
          // do work

          // thread delay or cancellation
          if(cancelToken.WaitOne(INTERVAL))
            break;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        { // expected exception on cancellation
          break;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { // your exception handling
        }
      }

      // perform shutdown
    }

    private void RecreateCancellationSource()
    {
      CancellationTokenSource oldSource;

      try
      {        
        oldSource = Interlocked.Exchange<CancellationTokenSource>(ref _cancelSource, new CancellationTokenSource());

        if (oldSource != null)
        {
          oldSource.Cancel();
          oldSource.Dispose();
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Debug.WriteLine("LongRunningWorker.DisposeCancellationSource exception: " + ex);
      }
      finally
      {
        oldSource = null;
      }
    }

    private void DisposeCancellationSource()
    {
      CancellationTokenSource oldSource;

      try
      {
        oldSource = Interlocked.Exchange<CancellationTokenSource>(ref _cancelSource, null);

        if (oldSource != null)
        {
          oldSource.Cancel();
          oldSource.Dispose();
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Debug.WriteLine("LongRunningWorker.DisposeCancellationSource exception: " + ex);
      }
      finally
      {
        oldSource = null;
      }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      _disposing = true;

      Stop();
      DisposeCancellationSource();

      _isDisposed = true;
      _disposing  = false;
    }
  }
```